# SQL Server bringing back inconsistent results

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am working on some reports that were created before I started in my current job. One of these reports is based on a view (SQL Server 2005).

This view is incredibly large and unwieldy, and for now, I won't post it because I think it's just too big. I'm not sure how it was produced - I'm guessing that it was produced in the designer because I can't see someone actually writing stuff like this. It's several pages long, and references 5 other views. Bottom line - it's complicated, and needs to be refactored/redesigned, but until we get time for that we're stuck with it.

Anyway, I have to make some minor non-functional changes to it in order to move it to a different database and schema. In order to make sure I'm not changing what it actually returns, I'm amending a second version of the view. Let's call the first view vw_Data1 and my new view vw_Data2. Now, if I write:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM
(
SELECT * FROM vw_Data1
UNION
SELECT * FROM vw_Data2
)
```

then I should get back the same number as if I just did

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM vw_Data1
```

as long as vw_Data1 and vw_Data2 return identical rows (which is what I want to check).

However, what I am finding is if I run the UNION query above several times, I get DIFFERENT RESULTS EACH TIME.

So, just to be clear, if I run:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM
(
SELECT * FROM vw_Data1
UNION
SELECT * FROM vw_Data2
)
```

more than once, then I get different results each time.

As I say, I'm not posting the actual code yet, because the first thing I want to ask is simply this - how on earth can a query return different results?

There is one non-deterministic function used, and that is as part of the following (horrible) join:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.vwuniversalreportingdata_budget 
     ON 



CASE
    WHEN dbo.f_tasks.ta_category = 'Reactive' THEN
        CAST(dbo.f_tasks.ta_fkey_fc_seq AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            + ' | ' 
                + CAST(dbo.f_tasks.ta_fkey_fcc_seq AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                    + ' | ' 
                        + CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dbo.f_tasks.ta_sched_date)) AS VARCHAR(10))
    WHEN dbo.f_tasks.ta_category = 'Planned' THEN
        CAST(dbo.f_tasks.ta_fkey_fc_seq AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            + ' | ' 
                + CAST(dbo.f_tasks.ta_fkey_fcc_seq AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                    + ' | ' 
                        + CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dbo.f_tasks.ta_est_date)) AS VARCHAR(10))
    WHEN dbo.f_tasks.ta_category = 'Periodic' THEN
        CAST(dbo.f_tasks.ta_fkey_fc_seq AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            + ' | ' 
                + CAST(dbo.f_tasks.ta_fkey_fcc_seq AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                    + ' | ' 
                        + CAST(YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, dbo.f_tasks.ta_est_date)) AS VARCHAR(10))
END
= dbo.vwuniversalreportingdata_budget.id
```

The whole query is pretty disgusting like this. Anyway, any thoughts on how this could happen would be gratefully received. Is it something to do with the union, perhaps? I don't know. Help!

Comment: Two obvious reasons you probably already investigated. The current datetime is different and affects the results. The source data has been updated between runs.

Comment: If it's reproducable like you say, remove the select count(*) and diff the different outputs.

Comment: Agree with Lieven. Full join the two and output only `WHERE vw_Data1.ID IS NOT NULL OR vw_Data2.ID IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Hi guys.
Ok, so the datetime thing occurred to me - more on that below. Re: the source data changing, that's definitely not happening cos I'm working on a development server that no one else is accessing. Lieven, unfortunately, the views don't have unique ids, so I can't do the check like you say - however, I've done something slightly different - see below.

Comment: I've since had the same problem again. This time I've whittled it down to something more manageable. So, the following query SHOULD NOT RETURN ANYTHING: `SELECT SUM(paid_amt) FROM f_payments INNER JOIN f_po_head poh ON paid_fkey_poh_seq = poh_seq INNER JOIN fsupply sup ON poh_fkey_sup_seq = sup_seq GROUP BY paid_invoice_numbr EXCEPT SELECT SUM(paid_amt) FROM f_payments pay INNER JOIN f_po_head poh ON paid_fkey_poh_seq = poh_seq INNER JOIN fsupply sup ON poh_fkey_sup_seq = sup_seq GROUP BY paid_invoice_numbr `

Comment: Sorry about the formatting here guys - I can't seem to work out how to display this properly. But essentially the above is a "SELECT A EXCEPT SELECT B" query, where A=B. It's like saying, "Select me all fruit which are not fruit". So it should NOT return anything. But it returns data. And what's more, it returns different data each time. My best theory on this is that the field "paid_amt" is a float, and this is causing the problems. But the problems you get with floats are usually consistent at least. i.e. they fail the same way each time. This, I just don't get.